# How can I use Scala code even more English like manner?

Tags: scala, dsl

I have a Scala program below:

```
object Fun extends App {
  class kid {
    def on = new kid
    def the(block: => Unit) = { block; "Scala is awesome!" }
  }

  println((new kid on) the {})
}
```

That `println((new kid on) the {})` line prints:

```
Scala is awesome!
```

How can I make usage of this line even more English like in Scala?

**EDIT**: Another approach by @Erik Allik :

```
object Fun extends App {
  class kid {
    def onThe(block: => Unit) = { block; "Scala is awesome!" }
  }
  println(new kid onThe {})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't make this work without the parens; without them the postfix call will cause ambiguity. I would just accept the fact that most of the time you can't achieve full English like sentence structure in most non-trivial cases and use a workaround such as `onThe` or skipping the `the` part and making `on` infix.

'the' is unneeded anyway because it's statically deduceable from context whether you mean a pre-existing name (the) or a new name i.e. free variable (a).

Also, I don't even find it very important or useful to achive 100% English like sentences unless it's a competition. In practice it might actually make things less readable *and* much more convoluted under the hood. If you really need something like natural language like DSL, define a new language grammar using Scala's powerful parser combinators. You should even be able to write, say, an Eclipse plugin to syntax highlight your custom DSL.

Comment: Could you share the code for your explanation in first paragraph?

Comment: @tuxdna: sorry, I see you've already figured it out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

This might improve readability a bit.
A common idiom would be to use a **companion object** to get rid of the *new*.
If you can live with the added *.* you can get rid of some additional  parentheses.

```
object Fun extends App {

  class Kid() {
    def the(block: => Unit) = { block; "Scala is awesome!" }
  } 

  object Kid {
    def on = new Kid()
  }

}
```

Then you can call your function in that way:

```
scala> println ( Kid.on the {} )
Scala is awesome!
```

Comment: I think the `new` in "new kid on the block" was kind of desirable... :)